# USB dongle hardware locked without switch

Tags: linux, windows, usb, partitioning

I'm currently facing a quite strange problem: my usb-dongle seems locked, but it doesn't have a hardware switch. I tried installing Debian on it, and throughout the installation-process, the drive should be formatted as ext4. This process got stuck at about 30% and failed, since then, the dongle seems hardware-locked.

I tried to format it using Windows built-in-tools, HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool (which usually solved this problem), RMPrep (which resulted in a write-error) and tried formatting it with fdisk on a Debian-Live-System. I also tried to overwrite the corrupted partition-table using dd, to fill the table with zeros, but as before, the device is labeled as read-only.

I'm 100% sure, that this dongle doesn't have a hardware lock on the outside. Everytime I overwrite the read-only-attribute using either `hdparm -r0 /dev/sdc` or using diskpart's `attrib disk clear readonly`, it seems that this doesn't take any effect on the device. If I unplug and reinsert it, the attribute is readonly again. Diskpart also labels the `current readonly state` as readonly.

I don't care about this giveaway usb dongle, but I already had a similar problem before on a bought one, that I threw away, because of missing manufacturer's guarantee.

How could I unlock the usb dongle again?

Comment: Sounds like a build-in protection against tampering. I would recommend contacting the manufacturer directly and asking for support.

Comment: I'm going to try this out, but I'm still curious, if there's a non-manufacturer-based solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know enough to answer that question with certainty.